# reactive typed class in VueJS3 with TypeScript

Tags: html, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have been programming with vueJS (3.x) and TypeScript for a few weeks and I have a problem with reactivity, I show you my scenario.

First I have the masterClass.ts file:

```
export default class masterClass {
    private _id: number;
    private _has_items: boolean;
    private _items: Array<detailsClass>;

    constructor() {
        this._id = 0;
        this._has_items = false;
        this._items = [];
    }

    get id(): number {
        return this._id;
    }

    set id(_value: number) {
        this._id = _value;
    }

    get has_items(): boolean {
        return this._has_items;
    }

    set has_items(_value: boolean) {
        this._has_items = _value;
    }

    get items(): Array<detailsClass> {
        return this._items;
    }

    set items(_value: Array<detailsClass>) {
        this._items = _value;
    }
}

export class detailsClass {
    private _id: number;
    private _price: number;
    
    constructor() {
        this._id = 0;
        this._price = 0;
    }

    get id(): number {
        return this._id;
    }

    set id(_value: number) {
        this._id = _value;
    }
    
    get price(): number {
        return this._price;
    }

    set price(_value: number) {
        this._price = _value;
    }
}
```

And the masterView.vue file:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="record != null">
        <label>Has Items</label>
        <select v-model="record.has_items">
            <option value="true">Yes</option>
            <option value="false">No</option>
        </select>
        
        <br><br>
        
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="element in record.items">
                    <td>{{ element.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ element.price }}</td>
                <tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    import masterClass from '...';
    
    const record = ref<masterClass | null>();
    
    onMounted(() => {
        record.value = new masterClass();
    });
</script>
```

How should I do so that when has_items is set to false the items list of the masterClass is cleaned. The point is that all the logic must be inside the masterClass class (I don't want to add code to the masterView).

I was thinking of doing it this way.

```
export default class masterClass {
    // ...

    get has_items(): boolean {
        return this._has_items;
    }

    set has_items(_value: boolean) {
        this._has_items = _value;
        
        if(!this._has_items) {
            this._items.splice(0); // Here 
        }
    }

    // ..
}
```

But it doesn't work, I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Try reactive instead of ref

Answer (score 1):

ref is a only reactive to shallow changes, if you want to have a deep reactivity you should use

```
// This is how to explicitly type a reactive
// Reactives must always be instantiated with an object
const record: MasterClass = reactive(new MasterClass())
```

This will also allow you to remove your onMounted hook as it is no longer needed.

I hope this helps you.